# Showing sets of the same cardinality have isomorphic symmetry groups

Tags: group-theory

Let $X$ and $Y$ be sets s.t. $|X|=|Y|$. Show that $Sym(X)\simeq{Sym(Y)}.$

By the first assumption there exists a bijection $\phi{:Sym(X)\rightarrow{Sym(Y)}}.$ I remain to show that this is a homomorphism. Hints?

Comment: Start with a bijection $f:X\to Y$.

Comment: ... and consider the map $\sigma\mapsto f \circ \sigma\circ f^{-1}$ on $Sym(X)$.

Comment: I have some confusion with $\sigma\circ{f}$. Let us say $X=\{p_1,p_2,...\}$ and $Y=\{q_1,q_2,...\}$. and let $\sigma{:=(p_1,p_4,p_7)}$ for example. does this mean. $\sigma\circ{f} = f(\sigma)=(f(p_1),f(p_4),f(p_7))$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you start with a bijection $f:X\to Y$. Recall that $Sym(X)$ is the set of all bijections $X\to X$. So now you need a map $F:Sym(X)\to Sym(Y)$.

Take some $\sigma\in Sym(X)$:

$$X \xrightarrow{\sigma} X$$

How can you transform it into some element of $Sym(Y)$? Well you have a bijection $f:X\to Y$ so lets use it:

$$Y\xrightarrow{f^{-1}} X \xrightarrow{\sigma} X\xrightarrow{f} Y$$

In other words define $F(\sigma)=f\circ\sigma\circ f^{-1}$. Since composition of bijections is a bijection then $F$ is a well defined function.

So now we have to prove two things:

1. $F$ is a group homomorphism.
2. $F$ is invertible.

Proof:

1. Take $\sigma,\gamma\in Sym(X)$. Then
   $$F(\sigma\circ\gamma)=f^{-1}\circ\sigma\circ\gamma\circ f=f^{-1}\circ\sigma\circ f\circ f^{-1}\circ\gamma\circ f=F(\sigma)\circ F(\gamma)$$
2. It is enough to find the inverse of $F$. And this is quite easy, take $G:Sym(Y)\to Sym(X)$ given by $G(\tau)=f^{-1}\circ\tau\circ f$. So the order is reversed. I leave it as an exercise that $G$ is the inverse of $F$.